# Web Notification on Click event in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, web-notifications

Edge Web Notification Click event : code to bring the corresponding window on top is not working. The same is working for other browsers which supports Notification. Please share your comments.

JavaScript code used:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(status){
    var n = new Notification('', {body: 'Hi',requireInteraction: true});
    n.onclick = function(event) {
        parent.focus();
        window.focus();
        window.open().close();
        this.close();
    };
});
```

System Details:

Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version 1703
OS Build: 15063.296

Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 15.15063

Comment: Even though the on Click action getting triggered , the Window.focus()/Window.Open methods are not able to bring the Edge window on Top. The same code was working in Edge before the latest windows update.

Comment: Added JSFiddle to Demo the Issue. Please run the same in chrome and Edge . Minimize the Browser window once Notification button is clicked. Then Click on the Notification window. In Case of Chrome Notification the Chrome window is taken to front., but Edge its not.

https://jsfiddle.net/jintujsfiddle/7qbn56f0/

Comment: Jintu, did you find the answer?